# Drilldown Chart Feasibility in KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui

I am looking to create a chart something like enclosed. This I tried creating in Microsoft Excel. Is it possible with KendoUI?

[image: KendoUI Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create something like this very easily. Here is an example, let me know if you need help personalize it.

Your html:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Your javascript:

```
<script>
    function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Chart Title"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "area",
                area: {
                    line: {
                        style: "smooth"
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [

               {
                name: "Late",
              color: "orange",
                data: [2, 2, 3, 4,4,5, 5,6, 6, 7]
            }, {
              type: "line",
                name: "Est DT",
              color:"grey",
                data: [2, 2, 4, 8,8,8, 8,8, 8,8]
            },
            {
                name: "On time",
              color: "blue",
                data: [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: ["Jan 19", "Feb 19", "Mar 19", "Apr 19", "Mai 19", "Jun 19", "Jul 19", "Aug 19", "Sep 19", "Oct 19"],
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(createChart);
    $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
</script>
```

some documentation about area charts 
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/area-charts/index

Comment: Thank you. That helped me with my requirement.