# Delimiting lines at every milestones

Tags: kendo-ui

I have been using a KendoUI chart as discussed in this URL [Drilldown Chart Feasibility in KendoUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954488/drilldown-chart-feasibility-in-kendoui)

I am wondering if Kendo supports providing an additional vertical line at a defined milestone. Or should we mix and match multiple graph types to accomplish this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the categoryAxis or valueAxis You can set minorGridLines or majorGridLines

```
categoryAxis: [{
    minorGridLines: {
      width: 3,
      color: "green"
    },
```

Or majorGridLines

```
majorGridLines: {
         visible: true // or width color and line type
         },
```

For more documentation please check https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.minorgridlines